# How can i add one day to my variable with momentjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

Hi there im trying to solve this but i cant ,
I want to calculate days of the month, without sunday and saturday

this is my code

```
        startOfMonth = moment().clone().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        endOfMonth = moment().clone().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        calculate(startOfMonth, endOfMonth);



calculate(start,end){
        var numWorkDays = 0;
        var currentDate = start;
        console.log(currentDate, end)
        while (currentDate <= end) {
            if (currentDate !== 1 && currentDate !== 7) {
                numWorkDays++;
            }
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'd').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            console.log(currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'd').format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
        }
        console.log(numWorkDays)
    },
```

but my function is counting only 14 days, and the days are incremented by two
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding days the right way.

The problem comes from the line with `console.log`, where add one day again. Juste remove or comment this line:

```
//console.log(currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'd').format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

Now, there's some other errors in your code and that's why you don't get what you expect:

- The numbers for Sunday and Saturday are `0` and `6`, not `1` and `7`
- In your code, `currentDate` is a string. So you are comparing, for example, `"2021-02-01"` with `1` and `7`. To get its number you have to create a date object from this string and then call `day()`

So the final code should look like this:

```
startOfMonth = moment().clone().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
endOfMonth = moment().clone().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        
function calculate(start,end){
        var numWorkDays = 0;
        var currentDate = start;
        while (currentDate <= end) {
          var currentDateAsNumber = moment(currentDate).day();
          var dayName = moment(currentDate).format('dddd');

            if (currentDateAsNumber !== 0 && currentDateAsNumber !== 6) {
                numWorkDays++;
            }
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'd').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            //console.log(currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'd').format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
        }
        console.log(numWorkDays)
    }

calculate(startOfMonth, endOfMonth);
```

I added a variable `dayName` too if needed.